# Initiating a class with a function that returns an array Python

Tags: python

Assuming that func() (no parameters) returns a list. In the following code I want self.myfunction to point to the function and not the returned list. How can I do this?

```
class myArrayThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,ThreadName, func):
        self.ThreadName = ThreadName
        self.myfunction = func
       # ......... more stuff after this
```

Comment: As Jasper says: https://eval.in/576365

Answer (score 3):

It already does what you want.

You are probably calling it the following way:

```
myArrayThread("some_name", func())
```

but it should be called

```
myArrayThread("some_name", func)
```

Comment: This was exactly the source of my problem thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer instead of a comment for formatting purposes...

Your code already does exactly what you want:

```
>>> def a():
...  return [1]
... 
>>> b=a
>>> b
<function a at 0x7f4b6aeb96a8>
>>> b()
[1]
>>> a
<function a at 0x7f4b6aeb96a8>
```

`b` "points to" the function `a`. You have to call it to get the return value of `a` (or `b` which is just another name for the same thing, see last line)